# Laravel: Get last transaction of each user

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a `transactions` table and a `users` table.
Each transaction has a foreign key referring to an user.
I need to get last transaction of each user for a particular day.

I have written this function but it's returning first transaction of each user.

```
public function usersLastTransaction(Request $request)
{
    return DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.trigered_by')
        ->join('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
        ->whereDate('transactions.created_at', '2023-07-14')
        ->groupBy('transactions.trigered_by')
        ->select('transactions.*')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: You have to use relationships, not `DB::table`, so use a model, share it with us how your relationships are. Shouldn't you be using an `orderByDesc` in that query? Maybe `orderByDesc('transactions.id')`?

Comment: I believe you are looking for Aggregate Functions on a SQL group-by. Although complex aggregations are database-specific, some are standard (see `ISO/IEC 9075`), including the MAX function, that instructs the `ORDER BY` group to return the maximum value of a certain field, e.g. `SELECT *, MAX(created_at) as last_transaction FROM transactions GROUP BY triggered_by`. If this is what you are looking for, let me know and I'll post a proper Laravel code as an answer.

Comment: @EduardoPacheco this is what I exactly need.
Please add your code to this question's answer. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed on comments, you are looking for [Aggregate Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [how to use them on Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#grouping). On Laravel documentation there is an example of how to use the aggregate function `count(id)` as a raw select clause, we can do just the same with the `max(created_at)` function:

```
public function usersLastTransaction(Request $request)
{
    return DB::table('transactions')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.trigered_by')
        ->join('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
        ->whereDate('transactions.created_at', '2023-07-14')
        ->groupBy('transactions.trigered_by')
        ->selectRaw('transactions.*, MAX(transactions.created_at) AS latest')
        ->get();
}
```

This query on its own solves your issue, returning the timestamp of the latest created transaction for the given day. Nonetheless, as [mentioned by matiaslaurati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76689135/laravel-get-last-transaction-of-each-user?noredirect=1#comment135205517_76689135) your usage of Laravel is far from idiomatic. You should look into [Laravel's ORM: Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent) to achieve its full power. Once best practices are applied, your code should look like this:

```
$transactions = Transaction::query()
    ->has('triggeredBy.roles')
    ->whereDate('created_at', '2023-07-14')
    ->get();

$latestByUser = $transactions
    ->groupBy('triggered_by')
    ->map->max('created_at');
```

Dump of `$latestByUser`:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#3452
  #items: array:2 [
    // triggered_by => latest transaction timestamp
    13 => "2023-07-15 11:54:48"
    18 => "2023-07-15 02:01:34"
  ]
}
```

Not only readability is improved, as you are also working with a very powerful and elegant ORM. To reach this:

1. I created the `Transaction` model and its `BelongsTo` relation to `User`, called `triggered_by` (I'm assuming you cannot call it `user_id`, but it would be preferable);
2. I created `Role` model;
3. I created `User` model and its `BelongsToMany` relation through `model_has_roles` (pivot) to `Role` (standard relation name: `roles`)